# How to fix "error: You need to have libgpg-error.a", when compiling AIDE for ARM?

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, aide

I compiled GPG for ARM recently and had to compile libgpg-error in the process. Today I need to compile [AIDE](http://aide.sourceforge.net/) and the following error shows up during `./configure`:

> configure: error: You need to have libgpg-error.a installed to use libgcrypt.

I compiled libgpg-error again, with the `--enable-static` option on `./configure` and now I have a `libgpg-error.a` file in `/usr/local/lib`. Yet, the `configure` script from AIDE can't find it apparently. I checked the script but didn't find anything obvious inside.

I'm stuck here, what should I check next?

Answer (score 2):

I am using a debian system and installed the `libgpg-error-dev` package and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Via [this forum post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/aide-i-give-me-errors-about-prelink-in-spite-of-disabling-it-4175521756/), adding `--disable-static` to `./configure` was my fix. I'm installing in a web hosting environment as a user without sudo/root.

My full configure command is `./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-zlib  --disable-static`